# Yellowing of Melamine Window Sill From Amazon Echo

Tags: repair, cleaning, stain-removal, melamine

I just found out today that a plastic flower pot has turned my Melamine window sill yellow. There is another window sill where an Amazon Alexa turned it yellow too! Is there anything I can do to get them back to white?

Comment: Has it turned the sill yellow, or has it prevented that spot from being bleached by sunlight?

Comment: The sill is white, where the pot was (and where the Amazon Echo was) is yellow.

Comment: For any that care, I tried oxyclean powder.  I made a paste and let it set for 20 min, did nothing.

Comment: I recall reading an article about how people figured out how to un-yellow plastic computer equipment which had yellowed with age.